# Flow control in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

can we use flow control extensions in latest version of  selenium IDE? ie;selenium IDE 1.0.10. When I am executing the command 'gotolabel' it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Flow control extension are there for commands like gotoif etc
Go to [here](http://www.zhangkf.com/2010/02/51-elliot-selenium-ide-flow-control-goto-and-while-loops/)  and download file..Add as extension to selenium IDE in options tab

Answer (score 0):

You have to install flowcontrol plugin in FF to execute conditional commands like goto, gotoIf and while commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download and install '*Flow Control*' plugin from this [page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/).

Once you have downloaded and installed the *Flow Control* plugin, you can use the goto-label command as:

```
command: goto
target: my_label_name
```

Where '*my_label_name*' is the name of the label, which is defined at some point in the test case. A label can be defined as follows:

```
command: label
target: my_label_name
```

There are many other plugins available in the [selenium IDE download page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), which you may find useful.